# Stone meaning in the context

Tags: word-usage, word-meaning, vocabulary

I want to know what stone is meant by this conversation I took from my English book:

> Mr Trubble: Ouch! I just bit an olive and I've broken my tooth on the
> **stone**! Look!
>
> Mrs Trubble: Mm. So... where's the **stone**?
>
> Mr Trubble: Oh dear. I think I swallowed it.

Is stone a jewel, a piece of rock or what?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[**stone**](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/stone#Noun), noun

> 5. (*botany*) The central part of some fruits, particularly drupes; consisting of the seed and a hard endocarp layer.

Comment: And in this instance we know it means the pit of the fruit rather than a small rock or a jewel because Mr. Trubble says he's broken it on **the** stone, which can only mean the stone of the olive (assuming there's no other stone in the context). If he had said he'd broken it on **a** stone, then it would almost certainly mean a small rock.